# Slidshare API v1 embed

Tags: api, embed

We've been using Slideshare for a while without issues.

But today i got an error report, that the embedded content is no longer available.

This is the error message i'm getting:

> This embedded content is no longer valid. If you are the owner of this >content, please re-embed this content from SlideShare. Contact Us if you >have issues re-embedding your content.

We haven't changed anything in the implementation of the API, and this is the sample URL for the iframe embedding.

> https://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/54248876

Upload to this URL
https://www.slideshare.net/api/2/upload_slideshow, where we take the "SlideShowID" variable back from the response, and save that for embedding the content.

And using this for the EMBED URL in an iframe.

> //www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/{{ $specifics['slideshare_id'] }}

Which have been working fine up till yesterday/tonight.
I have not been able to find anything in the SlideShare support area or similar places regarding a similar issues.

- Did they change something recently?

Has any of you experienced the same, or is the solution to just fully adapt their new V2 API and using Secret URL's for embedding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue programmatically you can update your DB data retrieving all your slideshare using this API:

```
/get_slideshows_by_user
```

The resulting XML is quite simple to parse and found the **ID** and the **SlideshowEmbedUrl** for each slideshow:

```
    <Slideshow>
      <ID>54248876</ID>   
    ...  
      <SlideshowEmbedUrl>https://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/key/aaaaaaaaaa</SlideshowEmbedUrl>    
    ...    
    </Slideshow>
```

[Api documentation site](http://apiexplorer.slideshare.net/)

Comment: Yeah, i did a similar solution to the matter, and now it works like it always has again :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the Slideshare ID (eg. 49406278) with (key/tPZujl6Z4fjvro) a the end of the embed url src.

Comment: You need to retrieve your own  key from the slideshare site. Log in and go to My Uploads->Preview->Edit->Share then look for your Embed tag. Your key is somewhere in there.

Comment: Hey Maja, Yes thanks. I made a temp-fix with dynamicly loading the "secret key" when it's needed, on old content, and then auto-saving it with new content.